# What's the best way to stop Greek Fire?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm playing Assassin's Creed Revelations and I failed to defend one of our bases because the Greek Fire just tore through my defenses, so I'd like to know what the best combination of units is to stop him.

During the battle, I probably forget that several of our men were falling to their 'snipers' so I was a little undermanned, but what should I do next time I encounter Greek Fire?

Comment: These things are kicking my tail as well - but you can avoid being attacked in the first place if you're careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally beat one of these by simply stacking nothing but riflemen everywhere I could, with fully upgraded barricades with archers behind them to pick off the wusses so I could build up the rear barricades.  They never got through my first barricade until the Greek Fire showed up, and the 20+ riflemen I had managed to take him down.  (Fortunately, the barricades held long enough - he was almost out of range of most of my riflemen!)

For winning this, my first non-story Den Defense, I was rewarded with the Assassin Caltrop Unit and also this little thing called "Greek Fire Barricade" that I'm willing to bet will come in handy later. :)

Comment: Update: The Greek Fire barricade is actually a barricade with a flamethrower.  And there are much harder artillery units than the Greek Fire in your future...!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting lots and lots of caltrop bombers everywhere and shoot lots of cannon balls at it. While you're at it, try helping by shooting it with your gun.